# Django developement on pytools - auto-restart server after changes? (VS 2013)

Tags: python, django, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

Until now, I have only used pycharm under linux for django, but I thought I may give pytools a try. Unfortunately, I can't find out how to set up my server to auto-restart after changes. This is what pycharm does on default. I found a line somewhere to add

```
WATCH_FILE_CHANGES_MASK=*.py
```

to app environmental variables, but I can't find where I can do this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python Tools for Visual Studio (PTVS) doesn't currently allow you to set an environment variable for an active python project (https://pytools.codeplex.com/workitem/737). A workaround is to set the environment variable and launch the development server from outside Visual Studio. You can do this either globally or within a virtual environment.

**Using the global environment**

Set the environment variable "WATCH_FILE_CHANGES_MASK" to have a value of "*.py" as described at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682653(v=vs.85).aspx then from the project directory run

```
python .\manage.py runserver
```

**Within a virtual environment**

Edit the file env\scripts\activate.bat under the project directory and add the line

```
set "WATCH_FILE_CHANGES_MASK=*.py"
```

Then from the project directory activate the virtualenv

```
.\env\scripts\activate
```

and run the server

```
python .\manage.py runserver
```

Oddly neither setting the global environment variable nor editing the activate script have an effect on how the development server behaves when launched from within Visual Studio. Personally I prefer to launch the development server externally for this reason and also because of some limitations Visual Studio enforces while the server is running (no renaming, moving files, etc.) that are not relevant to django development.